# What is this illustration style called? Monochrome with pops of colour, realistic digital drawing

Tags: illustration, style-identification

[image: Tropical Vibes by Krizia Chan]

I love this style of illustration and would like to find some tutorials/articles about it but not sure what to call it for searching.

Lots more from the same artist here: https://kriziachan.com

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## Mixed Media Illustration

Generally called [Mixed Media Illustration](https://www.google.com/search?q=Mixed%20Media%20illustrations&rlz=1C5MACD_enFR506FR507&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiVuPuJi6zgAhV08eAKHYdNBKwQ_AUIDigB&biw=1891&bih=1151), this particular case it's about watercolor over pencil illustration.

Another artists with similar illustrations:

[Kelly Smith](https://www.illustrationweb.com/artists/KellySmith/view)

[image: Kelly Smith]

[Yoco Nagamiya](http://yoco-nagamiya.jp/archive/personal_works/fashion)

[image: Yoco Nagamiya]

[Ana Santos](https://www.anasantosilustracion.com/portfolio/blanco-y-negro)

[image: Ana Santos]